# Empty Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a bit of basic Tkinter code, and when I launch I get no errors, but my window is empty, even though I have added things to them. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233424/python-tkinter-empty-window) question here, but that does not help me, as I have what it says to do.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

def __init__(self,master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack

    self.sg = Button(frame, text = "Study Guide", command = self.studyGuide)
    self.sg.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    self.sg.pack()

    self.quizlet = Button(frame, text = "Quizlet", command = self.quizlet)
    self.quizlet.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.quizlet.pack()

    self.flashcard = Button(frame, text = "Flash Cards", command = self.flashcard)
    self.flashcard.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    self.flashcard.pack()

    self.quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
    self.quitButton.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self.quitButton.pack()

    self.text = Label(frame, text = "Social Studies Study Tool")
    self.text.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    self.text.pack()

def studyGuide(self):
    print("Study Guide")

def quizlet(self):
    print("Quizlet")

def flashcard(self):
    print("Flashcards")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"when I launch I get no errors."_ You don't? When I run this, I get `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .6242576 which already has slaves managed by pack`. Is this your _exact_ code? By the way, why are you using `grid` and `pack`? You're only supposed to use one.

Comment: @SpaceMagnet Did any of the below answers solve your problem? If so, it would be really nice if you could _accept_ one of them to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 2):

First, for every element that you call `grid` for, don't call `pack`. You only need to use one or the other. Second:

```
frame = Frame(master)
frame.pack
```

You appear to be missing a parentheses here.

```
frame = Frame(master)
frame.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up layout managers! Use either `pack()` or `grid()`, but not both.

If you use `pack`, add the `side` where to pack the items:

```
frame.pack() # note the missing () in your code
...
self.sg.pack(side=TOP)
```

If you use `grid()`, add `frame.grid()` to the top of your code:

```
frame.grid()
...
self.sg.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

Comment: Be careful how you word your answer. Typically you _do_ use both pack and grid, just not in the same parent, and not the way the OP is doing it. It's actually a best practice to use both within an app, because they each solve slightly different problems. Neither is truly a "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley Absolutely right! So, don't mix it in the same container, then. Thanks for the clarification!